# pwdAccountLockedTime on Openldap2.4

Tags: passwords, openldap, rhel6

I configured Openldap2.4 on RHEL6.5.

i applied default password policy on my ldap tree.

But, Account lock has been effectively applying only when i do su - username with wrong password .

But when i tried to check with login with putty session or direct ssh it is not applying.

Can any one please help me on the above issue ?.

when i tried using sudo su - testuser2.4

pwdFailureTime: 20150427095439Z
pwdFailureTime: 20150427095445Z
pwdFailureTime: 20150427095451Z
pwdAccountLockedTime: 20150427095451Z

But when i tried direct ssh or putty session with 3 failures still the 
policy not applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid using the `managerDN` user. That's for use by OpenLDAP itself, and it bypasses all overlays, specifically this one. The overlay will work if you're logging in as a user within the DIT.

Comment: I have the following configuration on slapd.conf.
#This enables the ppolicy overlday for our password policies and will be applicale to all users.
overlay ppolicy

#The object which contains all the password policies refer the ppolicy.ldif file for the policies.
ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=Policies,dc=company,dc=com"

#This would not return account locked in case the account is locked, for securty puppose.
ppolicy_use_lockout


can you suggest me what needs to be done from the above or how would i can disable managerDN

Comment: I didn't say anythig abotu disabling the managerDN. I said *not to use it* yourself, or by your applications. It isn't subject to the password policy. All other accounts are.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.But can you elaborate bit clear as am beginner to openldap

Comment: What part of 'don't use it yourself' don't you understand?

Comment: I Changed the DIT as per your instructions on slapd.conf file . But still pwdFailureTime and PwdAccountLockTime is not working. Expect the 2 attributes all of them working fine. Can you please suggest on the above configurations .

Comment: Hi!! Sorry for making some one to be trouble.  But, i made more configuration changes to resolve the above issue. Now when ever i tried to use ldapwhoami command with credentials to lock. It is working fine on the ldap server. But not on the ssh session or putty session. Please suggest me on where iam going wrong or any one faced the same issue.

Comment: one more addition to my trail .i commented ppolicy_default "cn=default,ou=Policies,dc=company,dc=com" on slapd.conf. But it is reflecting the pwdFailureTime stamp. But on locking the user accounts after the few wrong attempts...